# What is the following Radon-Nykodim derivative?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, radon-nikodym

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},\mathbf{P} )$  be a probability space and $$\xi :(\Omega,\mathscr{A},\mathbf{P} )\longmapsto(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$$ is a random variable, with $$\mathbf{Q}(B)=\mathbf{P}(\xi^{-1}(B))\;\;\forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) $$ distribution, where $\mathbf{Q}\ll\mathbf{P}$.

I was wondering, in this case what is the  $\frac{d\mathbf{Q}}{d\mathbf{P}}$ Radon-Nykodim derivative?

To understand it clearly, I also want to ask about the following statement whether it is true or not: If $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue-measure, and $\mathbf{Q}\ll\lambda$, then $\frac{d\mathbf{Q}}{d\lambda}=f$ is the ordinary probability density function?

I find it true by definition, because $$\mathbf{Q}\left(B\right)=\int_{B}fd\lambda.$$ Am I right?

Comment: How can you have $\mathbf{Q}\ll\mathbf{P}$ when $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ are defined on different spaces?  The last part is correct, where $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\lambda$ are both on the same space $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So I guess it was a meaningless question, therefore I think it is pointless to talk about the dQ/dP derivative. It has no meaning because even Q≪P has no meaning. Am I right? Sorry for the stupid question, I'm just very beginner in this topic. Thank you for the answer anyway. :DD